# Why can't I catch exception in different IO than () in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception

I want to catch all exceptions in IO String function. When I run this code:

```
import Control.Exception.Base

handler :: SomeException -> IO String
handler _ = return "Gotta catch'em all!"

boom :: IO String
boom = return (show (3 `div` 0))

get :: IO String
get = boom `catch` handler

main :: IO()
main = do
  x <- get
  print x
```

I get

```
exctest: divide by zero
```

However this code works:

```
import Control.Exception.Base

handler2 :: SomeException -> IO ()
handler2 _ = print "Gotta catch'em all!"

boom2 :: IO ()
boom2 = print $ show (3 `div` 0)

main :: IO()
main = do
  boom2 `catch` handler2
```

with result

```
> Gotta catch'em all!
```

When I change boom in first example to

```
boom = error "ERR"
```

The exception is caught ok. Why does it behave this way? What should I do to catch exception in first example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `()` vs. other types. Note that the following also doesn't catch:

```
boom = return $ error "ERR"
```

The reason `catch` won't do anything about that is that `return` is lazy, thus the error isn't actually triggered by `catch`, only if you try to *get at the contained value*.

It is for precisely this reason that the `Exception` module has [evaluate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate), which is equivalent to `return` but strict.

```
boom :: IO String
boom = evaluate . show $ 3`div`0
```